# Trouble reading online .csv file in php?

Tags: php, http, yql

Yahoo has a finance api which allows individuals to obtain current and historical stock information. They have multiple ways of retrieving this information, one of them is by using the Yahoo Query Language and the other is by just straight downloading/reading their .csv (comma separated file) files.

I found a very useful script for reading the csv files via php. However I only seem to be getting the first 9,000 characters or so of the csv file. I've tried playing with the file size to no avail and I'm wondering where exactly I'm being capped and if there is a way around this.

Is php capping me, is yahoo capping me (seems unlikely), or is it just that one can only pass so much information through the http protocol? I welcome any informed comments and really appreciate any constructive criticisms. My code is below:

```
<?php

// Setup Variables
$requestUrl = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31";

// Pull data (download CSV as file)
$filesize=1000000;
$handle = fopen($requestUrl, "r");
$raw = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);

echo $raw; //error checking, turns out the $raw is only about 8000 characters long


// Split results, trim way the extra line break at the end
$quotes = explode("\n",trim($raw));


foreach($quotes as $quoteraw) {
$quoteraw = str_replace(", I", " I", $quoteraw);
$quote = explode(",", $quoteraw);

echo $quote[0]."
"; // output the first element of the array, the Company Name
}

?>
```

EDIT: Will up-vote all constructive advice, thanks so much :)).

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php , it says "if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size." so i guess you read only one chunk. while-loop through the file instead to get all the contents. The manual also shows how to read the file with a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Dennis, I'll get right on that, CodeAngry's answer probably suits my needs better, but I definitely need to brush up on that anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Good question & useful information by Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$CSV = file_get_contents('http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31');
var_dump($CSV);
```

^ try this one on for size.

You only `fread` once. It's only natural you don't get the whole thing. It needs to be read until `feof`(). You can't expect TCP/IP to delivery your expected buffer size. You say `fread`() a maximum of ##### bytes but you get in return as much as the server wants to (/ can) send in one strike.

**PS**: To go full awesome, use `cURL`! But `file_get_contents` should do here.

Comment: CodeAngry, thank-you for your advice. The original php script I had, like I said  above, I found online. I'm not terribly familiar with using fread and I appreciate your advice on not only how I could use fread with feof to do this but how the file_get_contents function would likely fit my needs better. I just implemented the file_get_contents function into my script and I'm successfully retrieving all historical data. This answer fit my needs perfectly , thank you very much, +1, best answer.

Answer (score 3):

As it is csv file, use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead.

Sample code from php.net:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sumoanand, I appreciate your answer, would there be any advantage to using fgetcsv over file_get_contets like CodeAngry suggested above? +1.

Comment: yes, because your code can produce incorrect output if there is coma in the description column. In that case, your description field will also be divided by explode command. In fgetcsv, there is $enclosure parameter for the same which default to doublequotes.